# Create multidimensional array using map()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello experts,
Could you please recommend:

I have two tables:

```
<tr id='firs_table'>
<td id="team">team1</td><td>45</td>
<td id="team">team2</td><td>47</td>
</tr>
<tr id='second_table'>
<td id="team">team1</td><td id="service">service name1</td><td id="count">count1</td>
<td id="team">team1</td><td id="service">service name2</td><td id="count">count2</td>
<td id="team">team1</td><td id="service">service name3</td><td id="count">count3</td>
<td id="team">team2</td><td id="service">service name1</td><td id="count">count1</td>
<td id="team">team2</td><td id="service">service name2</td><td id="count">count2</td>
</tr>
```

I need to create dictionary like:

```
team1: ['service name1','service name2','service name3'], [count1,count2, count3]
team2: ['service name1','service name2'], [count1,count2]
```

could you please advise algorithm with jquery ?
I need that result in order create RGraph  graph.
Thank you in advance.

I could not provide any working example of jquery code, I could not find a way how to iterate over $("tr#first_table td"#team") value and compare it with $("tr#second_table td"#team"), if values are the same => return array of [[$("tr#second_table td"#service")], [$("tr#second_table td"#count")] ].

I mean, I could not find idea.

Comment: can we assume there is `<tr>` on every line above? Html shown isn't very valid. Also please show what you have tried

Comment: yes, there are <tr> for every shown table:

Comment: note that you can not repeat ID's in a  page

Comment: Selecting by ID will only return a single result, since IDs are unique.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need

```
var res = {}
$('table tr').each(function () {
    var cellText = $(this).find('td').map(function (i, el) {
        return $(el).text();
    }).get();
    if (!res[cellText[0]]) {
        res[cellText[0]] = [[],[]];
    }
    res[cellText[0]][0].push(cellText[1]);
    res[cellText[0]][1].push(cellText[2]);    
});
```

If you have a heading row can use `$('table tr:gt(0)')`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bo9jrr7j/)**</kbd>